# Powershell reading Json

Tags: powershell

I'm getting the following response through an API and I'm trying to pull data out of the JSON response. I'm interested in only pulling the clone.href when clone.name = ssh.

```
response: {
    "links":  {
        "clone":  [
            "@{href=ssh://sampleurl.com; name=ssh}",
            "@{href=https://sampleurl.com; name=http}"
        ],
        "self":  [
            "@{href=https://sampleurl.com}"
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm using the following to call the API:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $Header -Method POST -Body $Body|ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: Is this how the Json actually looks? Try using `ConvertTo-Json -Depth 30` and see if the Json looks like the one you have posted here

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```sh
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $Header -Method POST -Body $Body|ConvertTo-Json

$href = $result.links.clone | Where-Object Name -eq ssh | ForEach-Object href
$href # Output to console
```

This uses [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.2) to filter the `clone` array and `ForEach-Object` to extract the `href` property, using short form of `ForEach-Object -MemberName href`.

Alternatively you can use the following syntax:

```sh
$href = $result.links.clone.Where{ $_.Name -eq 'ssh' }.href
```

It uses PowerShell intrinsic method [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.2#where) for filtering.